# How to Call a Command from a Controller and use Debug mode?

Tags: php, symfony

If I execute a task using the console I can add --no-debug:

```
php app/console app:task-name web-user --no-debug
```

This is the function inside Controller that call the task 'task-name ' and it works properly

```
public function generateSomethingAction() {
    $kernel = $this->get('kernel');
    $application = new Application($kernel);
    $application->setAutoExit(false);
    $input = new ArrayInput(array(
        'command' => 'app:task-name'
    ));
    $output = new BufferedOutput();
    $application->run($input, $output);
    ......
```

I would like to know if is possible to add --no-debug if I call the command from a controller?

Comment: Try it - and if it doesn't work, then ask a different question?

Comment: You might be better off moving the functionality that generates the json into it's own service and then accessing the service from either the command or the controller.  That get's rid of all the Application nonsense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pass additional parameters that don't need values, you can just add them to the ArrayInput array with a value of "true".

E.g.

```
$input = new ArrayInput([
        'command'     => 'app:task-name',
        '--yell'      => true,
        '--no-debug'  => true,
    ]);
```